# How do I solve the 'Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default' error in my Blazor app?

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side, cdn

I am working on an extremely simply Blazor application that will serve as a demo for a presentation that I am doing for work.
I am having an issue importing a js module that is supposed to add confetti when I click a button.

My js file, named Confetti.js, is as follows:

```
import JSConfetti from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-confetti@latest/dist/js-confetti.browser.js"

var jsConfetti = new JSConfetti();

function startConfetti() {
    jsConfetti.addConfetti();
}

export { startConfetti };
```

My Host file is as follows:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorServerApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorServerApp.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-confetti@latest/dist/js-confetti.browser.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./js/Confetti.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the script tag here becuase I was tring to use `import JSConfetti from 'js-confetti'`.

The Blazor component that I am trying call the function from is as follows:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

@page "/UsingState"
<h3 class="@currentColor color">UsingState</h3>

<div class="colors">
    @foreach(var color in Enum.GetValues<COLORS>())
    {
        <div @onclick="() => SetColor(color)" class="@color color">@color.ToString()</div>
    }
</div>

<div @onclick="Confetti">Confetti!</div>


@code {

    enum COLORS { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, INDIGO, VIOLET }

    COLORS currentColor = COLORS.RED;

    void SetColor(COLORS newColor)
    {
        currentColor = newColor;
    }

    async void Confetti()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("startConfetti");
    }
}
```

I have tried various configurations for the imports, but I haven't been able to get anything to work. I expected to be able to just call the "startConfetti" function and just have it work.